# how to sort a multidimensional array with one column in ascending order and another column in descending order?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

My question is about  two dimensional list sort in Python,a third party toolkit is not allowed for this question.

Suppose there is a two dimensional  `Students` list which stores the information of some student,the first column is `id`,the second is `name`,the third is `age`,you are required to sort the list **according to `age` as first keyword in descending order,but `name` as second keyword in ascending order**,that is,if `studentA` and `studentB` are of the same age,then sort the list by `name` in  ascending order.

the ref code is as below,

```py
students = [[3 , 'Jack' , 12] , [2 , 'Rose' , 13] , [1 , 'Tom' , 10] , [5 , 'Sam' , 12] , [4 , 'Joy' , 8]]
print(f"according to age as first keyword,name as second keyword in reverse order：\
{sorted(students , key=(lambda x: [x[2] , x[1]]) , reverse=True)}")
```

and the output is

```
[[2, 'Rose', 13], [5, 'Sam', 12], [3, 'Jack', 12], [1, 'Tom', 10], [4, 'Joy', 8]]
```

**but the desired result is**

```
[[2, 'Rose', 13],  [3, 'Jack', 12], [5, 'Sam', 12], [1, 'Tom', 10], [4, 'Joy', 8]]
```

how can we modify the code to get the right outcome?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `key` but with a small change, and using `-` counts as "descending" (negative numbers always come before positive numbers in an ascending order sort). So you don't have to use the `reverse` parameter at all.

```
>>> sorted(students, key = lambda x:(-x[2], x[1]))
[[2, 'Rose', 13], [3, 'Jack', 12], [5, 'Sam', 12], [1, 'Tom', 10], [4, 'Joy', 8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import operator 
list1 = sorted(students, key=operator.itemgetter(2), reverse=True)
print(list1)
```

Comment: it also woked,thank you for your answer,however it only sorts according to one column,for example ,if we change the input to this ``` students = [[5 , 'Sam' , 12] ,[3 , 'Jack' , 12] , [2 , 'Rose' , 13] , [1 , 'Tom' , 10] ,  [4 , 'Joy' , 8]]```,it can't produce the expected ans.